# Trouble getting the original app version that the user installed (receipt validation)?

Tags: ios7, in-app-purchase, storekit, receipt-validation

I have an app that I recently updated to work with in app purchases. The previous version (paid but with no in app purchases) was 1.0 and the current version is 1.1.

As the in app purchase essentially unlocks all features (which were included in the paid version 1.0), I wanted a way for users that had originally downloaded version 1.0 to be upgraded if they pressed my restore purchases button.

To do this, I first try to restore purchases and if the response to:

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```

If this provides me with a queue with a transactions count of 0, I check the receipt to see if the original version installed was 1.0.

The code to get the receipt is as per Apple's documentation

```
- (void)tryRestoreFromOriginalPurchase
{
    // Load the receipt from the app bundle
    NSError *error;
    NSData  *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]];

    if (receipt == nil) {
        [self restoreFromOriginalVersionWithReceipt:nil];
        return;
    }

    // Create the JSON object that describes the request
    NSDictionary *requestContents = @{@"receipt-data": [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]};
    NSData       *requestData     = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestContents options:0 error:&error];

    if (!requestData) {
        [self restoreFromOriginalVersionWithReceipt:nil];
        return;
    }

    // Create a POST request with the receipt data
    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *storeRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:storeURL];

    [storeRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [storeRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];

    // Make a connection to the iTunes Store on a background queue
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:storeRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (!connectionError) {
            NSError      *error;
            NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

            if (jsonResponse) [self restoreFromOriginalVersionWithReceipt:jsonResponse];
            else              [self restoreFromOriginalVersionWithReceipt:nil];
        } else {
            [self restoreFromOriginalVersionWithReceipt:nil];
        }
    }];
}
```

This then calls the following method:

```
- (void)restoreFromOriginalVersionWithReceipt:(NSDictionary *)receipt
{
    if (receipt == nil) {
        // CALL METHOD TO HANDLE FAILED RESTORE
    } else {
        NSInteger status = [[receipt valueForKey:@"status"] integerValue];

        if (status == 0) {
            NSString *originalApplicationVersion = [[receipt valueForKey:@"receipt"] valueForKey:@"original_application_version"];

            if (originalApplicationVersion != nil && [originalApplicationVersion isEqualToString:@"1.0"]) {
                // CALL METHOD TO HANDLE SUCCESSFUL RESTORE
            } else {
                // CALL METHOD TO HANDLE FAILED RESTORE
            }
        } else {
            // CALL METHOD TO HANDLE FAILED RESTORE
        }
    }
}
```

Now this doesn't work. When someone installs version 1.1 and taps restore purchases, it restores successfully when it shouldn't.

**I've just realized that in my Info.plist, my CFBundleShortVersionString is 1.1 but my CFBundleVersion is 1.0.**

This may be a really daft question, but is the receipt providing an original_application_version of 1.0 (due to the wrong CFBundleVersion) even though the update is versioned 1.1?

So if I release a new update with this corrected to say version 1.2 (for both the CFBundleShortVersionString and CFBundleVersion), will the problem be resolved?

**-- UPDATE --**

So I just uploaded a new version to the app store with both the CGBundleVersion and CFBundleShortVersionString equal to 1.2. However, I'm still facing the same problem - users downloading version 1.2 for the first time and tapping on restore purchases are being upgraded for free (due to the receipt check outlined above). It seems the original_application_version is always coming to 1.0.

Note: I am downloading the app under a new iTunes account that has not previously downloaded the app.

Here is the receipt I have if I install from the app store and then try to get the receipt through Xcode

```
2014-08-27 08:46:42.858 AppName[4138:1803] {
    environment = Production;
    receipt =     {
        "adam_id" = AppID;
        "application_version" = "1.0";
        "bundle_id" = "com.CompanyName.AppName";
        "download_id" = 94004873536255;
        "in_app" =         (
        );
        "original_application_version" = "1.0";
        "original_purchase_date" = "2014-08-26 22:30:49 Etc/GMT";
        "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1409092249000;
        "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2014-08-26 15:30:49 America/Los_Angeles";
        "receipt_type" = Production;
        "request_date" = "2014-08-26 22:46:42 Etc/GMT";
        "request_date_ms" = 1409093202544;
        "request_date_pst" = "2014-08-26 15:46:42 America/Los_Angeles";
    };
    status = 0;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: In case any one comes past this and has the same problem, I could not get the above code to work. Instead, I got the desired result by checking against the original_purchase_date.

Comment: I tried this code, but every time it says receipt = nil.

Comment: @NCF any luck with this?

Comment: @sheefy would you say that even now you're more comfortable with the original_date instead of the version number? I'm about to do the same, is your code above current enough to be re-used?

Comment: @NCFUSN Are testing locally by running from Xcode? If so, the receipt will be nil IIRC. Create a TestFlight build and you'll get a receipt

Answer (score 21):

I stumbled upon the same issue - I converted my app from paid to freemium and tried to use `original_application_version` in the app receipt to decide who to unlock the new freemium features for. I, too, was unsuccessful.

However, what I found out was that I was using `original_application_version` incorrectly. The name misled me into thinking that this string corresponds to the version number of the app. On iOS, it does not. `original_application_version` is actually the **build** number of the app.

> **Original Application Version**
>
> This corresponds to the value of **CFBundleVersion** (in iOS) or
>   **CFBundleShortVersionString** (in macOS) in the Info.plist file when the
>   purchase was originally made. In the sandbox environment, the value of this field is always “1.0”.
>
> Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html

I think this could be the reason why you are getting a number you are not expecting.

Using `original_purchase_date`, as you did in the end, is a reliable alternative though.

Comment: I can also confirm that `original_application_number` is the build number for the original version, which is next to useless for determining the actual original version. So when I switched to freemium I changed my build numbers to prefix with the version number. So for version 2.1.5 build 1 would be 2.1.5.1. Pre-freemium versions always had a single digit build number so it was now easy to distinguish original customers from new.

Answer (score 8):

It's been a while since this question was asked, but it raises some very important points:

The original app version field in the receipt corresponds to CFBundleVersion, not CFBundleShortVersionString.  In a sandbox (developer build) environment, the value string is **always** "1.0".

Note that when converting from a paid app to freemium, if an original (paid version) user uninstalls the app, then reinstalls from iTunes, there will be no local receipt.  Calling `SKPaymentQueue restoreCompletedTransactions` will not cause a new receipt to be downloaded if that user has never made an in-app purchase.  In this situation, you need ask for a receipt refresh using `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` and not rely on restore functionality.