# Determine new installation vs. update without user defaults

Tags: ios, installation, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I read this: [Check if my IOS application is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899503/check-if-my-ios-application-is-updated)
(and its duplicate: [How to detect an iOS App installed or upgraded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118943/how-to-detect-an-ios-app-installed-or-upgraded) ), but all answers are about to store something into the user defaults in advance.

These are good answers if you are provident enough, but what if I want to determine it with an update? (And this update can be a new installation for new users.) There's nothing in the user defaults regarding this, so I need a solution for an already existing application. Is there an API for that?

Comment: You can check the version (which is actually the build) that was originally purchased from the receipt. If you reset your build number with each new version, this won't help you, but if your build number always increases this might help.

Comment: Luckily it's increasing, so I'll check it. Do you know how to access the receipt?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47924123/how-to-get-the-original-application-version-the-first-purchased-version-number

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Keychain, save the version in the device, and check if the installed version is newer or not, this variable remains stored even when a user deletes the application unlike the UserDefault variables.
I hope I can help. Let me know.

Comment: Well, it works for the future. Given an app without any version storage in the past, how can I determine that it's a fresh installation, or an update?

Comment: I can't think of any other solution at the moment.